# ASP.NET MVC changed view name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I changed the name of view files (Index.cshtml -> Performance.cshtml), and when I execute the project, the application can't recognise the new view name. I changed the name of an action in controller accordingly (ActionResult Index() -> ActionResult Performance()). However, it keeps saying HTTP 404 error.

Comment: Have you rebuild the project ?

Comment: Did you check your `RouteConfig.cs` file? By default, there will `Index` View targeting and when you run the page, it will first go through RouteConfig.cs to check the route...

Comment: Yes. Cleaned the old build and did rebuild.

Comment: What url are you getting? If you intend to change from Index(which is default) to something else, you gotta put the controller's name in the url !

Comment: please share you route config.cs and action code...

Comment: Thanks guys. It's now fully working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  you change your view name mvc application can't find a proper view for it's controller action method.

If it is your default page view( load on application start) than you also need to make changes in your Route_config file.
See the image below  [image]  Change `controller = " Name_of_controller"` & `action="name_of_action"`  in your case action name will be **Performance**.
Always Remember in mvc you can run any method using browser url
 **for example** : controller is home & method is Performance than url will be *localhost:port/home/Performance*

Answer (score 1):

Change the default route defined in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file to set Performance as the default action.

Or, you can run the project with the following URL:`http://localhost:port/home/Performance`